# Using spf13/cobra package result in error 'unknown flag'

Tags: go

Just started using `spf13/cobra` and run into error on the very first try:

[image]

How the flag could be 'unknown' if it listed in the help section of command itself ?

Application created by following most popular tutorials in top Google results when search for cobra command

here is the code for `root command` in `\cmd` folder

```
package cmd

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "github.com/spf13/cobra"
)

var (
    cfgFile string
)

// rootCmd represents the base command when called without any subcommands
var rootCmd = &cobra.Command{
    Use: "cobra-test",
    Run: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {
        fmt.Println("running with config file: ", cfgFile)
    },
}

// Execute adds all child commands to the root command and sets flags appropriately.
// This is called by main.main(). It only needs to happen once to the rootCmd.
func Execute() {
    err := rootCmd.Execute()
    if err != nil {
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}

func init() {
    // Here you will define your flags and configuration settings.
    // Cobra supports persistent flags, which, if defined here,
    // will be global for your application.

    rootCmd.PersistentFlags().StringVar(&cfgFile, "config", "", "config file (default is $HOME/.cobra-test.yaml)")
    // rootCmd.MarkPersistentFlagRequired("config")

    // Cobra also supports local flags, which will only run
    // when this action is called directly.
    rootCmd.Flags().BoolP("toggle", "t", false, "Help message for toggle")
}
```

here is the `main.go`

```
package main

import "cobraTest/cmd"

func main() {
    cmd.Execute()
}
```

here is `launch.json` file:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch Package",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "auto",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/main.go",
            "args": [
                "--config /some/config/file.yaml"
            ]
        }
}
```

Comment: Please do not post images of text.

Comment: The error is coming from `dlv` — not your program. It says `Type 'dlv help' for list of commands`. If you need to pass arguments directly to the underlying program, separate them with `--`. For example: `dlv debug main.go -- --config foobar`.

Comment: what should I change in `launch.json` ?

Comment: @coxley the error isn't coming from dlv, according to the output.

Comment: @Adrian Derp, my mistake! It wasn't clear to me how the program was being executed (not sure what a launch.json is without context).

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
            "args": [
                "--config /some/config/file.yaml"
            ]
```

Passes "--config /some/config/file.yaml" to your application *as a single argument*, as if in the shell you had run:

```
mycommand '--config /some/config/file.yaml'
```

Which is why the error says the unknown flag is "--config /some/config/file.yaml" and not, as you'd expect, something like "--config".

Just change it to:

```
            "args": [
                "--config",
                "/some/config/file.yaml"
            ]
```

so that it's equivalent to:

```
mycommand --config /some/config/file.yaml
```

And you should be good to go.